# Inline PHP clone

Tags: php, clone, inline

When trying to do this in PHP 5.2.9:

```
$foo = (clone $template)->bar();
```

PHP gives me a syntax error:

```
Parser error "';' expected after expression (Found token: ->)"
```

Am I doing something wrong? or is there simply no way to clone an object inline, such that I would have to split my statement into two lines?

Comment: I don't remember details, but older versions of PHP had trouble with some expressions related to object properties.  Maybe this was one of them?  Can you upgrade your version of PHP?

Comment: @Brad Same problem with newer PHP versions but error is different.

Comment: PHP 7 now supports this https://3v4l.org/D5Vd9

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, PHP does not allow that syntax (in any version).  As an alternative to breaking it into two lines, you can do this:

```
$foo = call_user_func(array(clone $template, 'bar'));
```

Comment: Too bad, I thought PHP had overcome those oddities by version 5. I'll consider the `call_user_function` version ;-)

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to one-line this.  Or if there is, I don't know what it is :)

Comment: Here's to hoping this gets added in PHP 7.

Answer (score 3):

```
class X {
    public function foo(){
        echo 'inline clone';
    }
}

$x = new X;

$y = clone $x and $y->foo(); // "inline clone"
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be available only from PHP 5.4.0

Reading changelog:

> Added class member access on instantiation (e.g. (new foo)->bar())
>   support.

Comment: Unfortunately, this syntax only works with `new`.  It does not work with `clone` https://eval.in/123192 :(

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could create a function to clone a variable:

```
$clone = function ($value) {
    return clone $value;
};

$foo = $clone($template);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newObject = (clone $objectToClone);
```

(Wont work in older verions of PHP, ok in 7.something+ though)